# How do I replace and insert what kind of missing pin - bolt in a home fused disconnect box?

Tags: electrical, wiring, circuit-breaker, canada

[image: the original pin may look like this]

Power from Hydro (the electric company) runs into this disconnect box then continues to the meter. I'm looking for help as to what I should use to replace the missing bolt or pin that connects the on/off lever clip? Am I correct that current doesn't run through the clip area?

An electrician wants 150 bucks for what looks like a 2 minute job. Hydro is putting the squeeze on me to get this done as they are sticking me with a smart meter.

[image: what kind of clip or bolt is missing?]

[image]

Comment: Parts: 1 clip = $3.00, 1 bolt = $0.80. Labor: 2 minutes @ $36.00/hour = $1.20. Knowing which clip and bolt to install = $145.00.

Comment: Not electrocuting yourself while installing clip and bolt **priceless**

Comment: Who made this box? Can you post photos of the labeling? (It appears to be some flavor of enclosed/safety switch, listed to UL98 or equivalent, but I can't tell whose, and that's important for getting service parts)

Comment: Labeling? This thing might be 80 yrs old and painted over tons of times, can't see any id on it. Estimates start at $600 Cdn to replace the box with a new? wire from the roof to inside our kitchen. I'm trying to go with the $150 electrician for his 2 minutes of time to put a clip. I've contacted over 20 electricians to try to get estimates for a total remake. During the course of this I 've come to the conclusion that electricians are exploitative, lazy and unreliable, far worst than the car salesmen I've come into contact with.

Answer (score 2):

Contact the manufacturer.  These things are not listed for unit repair using random hardware store parts.  Expect Hydro to disapprove any funny looking repairs.

That is not simply a lever.  There's a mechanism in there, that is important to the ability to "break" high current flows.

Do not attempt any repair without consulting with the manufacturer. If this is a common thing with an easy and proper fix, they will have it.

Regardless, this job is a big problem **because this equipment is hot at all times**.  If it's before the meter, *even pulling the meter* will not de-energize it; which makes working on it a dicey affair even for an electrician.  This is an unfused load that could pull as much as 25,000 amps straight off the transformer.  At this scale, arc-flash gets **serious**.

It is excessively rare for me to say "this should not be DIYed", but if pulling the meter won't de-energize it, I so say.  In that case, to de-energize it, they would need to get in a bucket and go unhook it from the pole line.  Once thus de-energized, have a field day, but again don't do any repairs the manufacturer doesn't endorse. I would sooner just replace the box with one that will be reliable.

Comment: Harper, from the 3rd image just uploaded you can see the box is indeed before the meter. I asked for a quote to install a new breaker panel with cut/off included but was told I will still need a fused disconnect switch box. I don't understand why. The the electrician would reconnect the missing link for $150 if it would be so dangerous why would he do it? - I thank you for your much appreciated information.